# Google maps sdk - doesn't move the view to new point

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

Seems to be a very simple task but for some reason it doesn't work.

I init the map and place the 1st location this way:

```
    self.view = self.mapView
    self.mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    let KBPLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.341707, 30.893606)
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: KBPLocation.latitude, longitude: KBPLocation.longitude, zoom: 12)
    self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
```

then i have an func that does this:

```
func moveToNextLocation()   {
        self.mapView?.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.778577, longitude: -122.419063, zoom: 15)
}
```

i expect it to move the map to the new point. but it doesn't. 
if i add this line to my function `self.view = self.mapView` it will work but it doesn't have this transition animation from one point to another but it just shows the location instantly. also i think it's not a right approach assigning the `mapView` to `view` again.

please help me to figure out why it doesn't move ?

thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** ps: i'm using this tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wPjCdDn2wo) and it's on 15th minute where it adds the new location

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by moving:

```
self.view = self.mapView
```

after the line:

```
self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
```

I guess the reason is that I needed to assign to view after init of map.